# Assign variable with IIF statement

Tags: vba, textbox, iif

Trying to declare the variable 'shipping' with value of TextBox1 but only if TextBox1 is not empty. If it is empty I want the variable to say 0.

Code I have just isn't doing it. Still null.

Also, the same rule will apply to many other textboxes, how would I set this rule in a public function to be reusable?

```
Dim shipping As String
shipping = IIf(Ismpty(TextBox1.Value), 0, TextBox1.Value)
```

Comment: `Ismtpy` - just use `IsNothing()`

Comment: Or at least spell it as `IsEmpty`.

Comment: You're assigning `0` to a `String`?

Comment: @JeremyThompson `IsNothing` is VB.NET, doesn't exist in VBA :) Besides @OP my favorite option is the check `Len(Trim(TextBox1.Value))=0`

Comment: @A.S.H you're right but Is and Nothing are valid VBA `TextBox1.Text Is Nothing`

Comment: @JeremyThompson True, `Is Nothing` is valid. (beware that VBA `String`s are not objects, though). :)

Comment: @A S H worked well! Rgds

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

Case 1 - desired output of "shipping" is a Number

```
Dim shipping As Double
shipping = IIf(IsNumeric(TextBox1.Value), TextBox1.Value, 0)
```

Case 2 - desired output of "shipping" is a String

```
Dim shipping As String
shipping = IIf(TextBox1.Text <> "", TextBox1.Text, "0")
```

Comment: I only score 11, accepting my question will help getting closer :-)

Comment: hi @joell dont worry you'll soon accumulate so many points that you'll find it hard to keep track:). anyway, i asked you about accepting (not to be confused with voting) so as to indicate that it's not an open item any more. only answers are accepted, there's no option to accept questions